Change content-type for SOAP request in .Net6.0
I have a soap1.1 client in .Net6.0 that workes fine. Now the server changed and uses content type application/xml instead of text/xml. How can I change my BasicHttpBinding to accept application/xml?
I tried to use WSHttpBinding, but it's for SOAP1.2 and uses application/soap+xml what the server doesn't accept.
Currently I am trying to write a custom binding, but have problems with implementing client certificate authentication.
Here is my code snippet:
var binding = 
    new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
binding.ProxyAddress = null;
ChannelFactory<MyChannel> cf = new ChannelFactory<MyChannel>
    (binding,
    new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("...."));
cf.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = 120;
.... add cert ....
_soapClient = cf.CreateChannel();

Here is the Exception I get:
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Der Inhaltstyp application/xml der Antwortnachricht stimmt nicht mit dem Inhaltstyp der Bindung (text/xml; charset=utf-8) überein. Wenn Sie einen benutzerdefinierten Encoder verwenden, muss die IsContentTypeSupported-Methode korrekt implementiert sein.
